# OData routing in Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to enable `OData` in Web Api. I created `OData` routing, and a controller that inherits from `ODataController`, and I want to get some sample data from my application. Here's my code:

```
public class TicketController : BaseWebApiController //inherits from ODataController
{
     [EnableQuery]
     public IQueryable<TicketModel> Get()
     {
         return (_ticketService.GetAll());
     }

     [EnableQuery]
     public SingleResult<TicketModel> Get([FromODataUri] int id) 
     {
         return (_ticketService.Get(id));
     }
```

`_ticketService` is a mock service that returns sample data from a static List of TicketModel using `AsQueryable()` method. It works fine.

```
public static class ODataConfig
{
    public static void EnableOData(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "api", GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
        config.EnsureInitialized();
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<TicketModel>("Ticket");
        var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
        return edmModel;
    }
}
```

`ODataConfig.EnableOData(config)` is then called in `App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` Register method.

The problem is, while url `http://localhost:52074/api/Ticket` calls `Get()` method properly, a url request of `http://localhost:52074/api/Ticket(1)` also calls `Get()` instead of `Get(1)`. I tried to append `ODataRouting("({id})")` attribute but all it does is throw an exception with message

> "The path template on the action in controller is not a valid OData path template".

Has anybody had that problem before? Any ideas? Help appreciated.

PS. It's my first question here so if something is missing, let me know.

Answer (score 5):

1. You should rename your `id` to `key`, then `http://localhost:52074/api/Ticket(1)` will route to `Get(1)`.
2. If you want to use ODataRoute, the attribute should be like: `[ODataRoute("Customers({id})")]`.
3. FYI

   [OData website](https://odata.org)

   [OData Documentation](https://odata.github.io/WebApi/)