# odata webapi routing issue: get method with identifier not matched

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am new to OData. For learning purposes (guided by [this](http://www.odata.org/blog/how-to-use-web-api-odata-to-build-an-odata-v4-service-without-entity-framework/) tutorial), I have set up a sample WebApi like the following (Only pasting what I consider relevant).

Configuration:

using DataApi.Models;

```
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData.Batch;
using System.Web.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;

public static class WebApiConfig
{ 
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
      config.MapODataServiceRoute("od", null, GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
      config.Count()
        .Filter()
        .OrderBy()
        .Expand()
        .Select()
        .MaxTop(null);     
    }

 private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
      ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
      builder.Namespace = "Demos";
      builder.ContainerName = "DefaultContainer";
      builder.EntitySet<Code>("Code");      
      var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
      return edmModel;
    }
}
```

The Model Classes:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DataApi.Models
{
  public class Code
  {

    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Validity Validity { get; set; }
    public Code Parent { get; set; }
  }
}

namespace DataApi.Models
{
  public class Validity
  {
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
  }
}
```

The Controller:

```
using DataApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData;

namespace DataApi.Controllers
{
  [EnableQuery]
  public class CodeController : ODataController
  {
    private List<Code> _codes;

    public CodeController()
    {
      _codes = new List<Code>();

      Validity validity = new Validity()
      {
        From = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1),
        To = new DateTime(2018, 12, 31)
      };
      Code code1 = new Code() { Id = 1, Value = "1", Validity = validity };

      _codes.Add(code1);
      _codes.Add(new Code() { Id = 2, Value = "1.1", Parent = code1, Validity = validity });
      _codes.Add(new Code() { Id = 3, Value = "1.2", Parent = code1, Validity = validity });
      _codes.Add(new Code() { Id = 4, Value = "1.3", Parent = code1, Validity = validity });
      _codes.Add(new Code() { Id = 5, Value = "1.4", Parent = code1, Validity = validity });
      _codes.Add(new Code() { Id = 6, Value = "1.5", Parent = code1, Validity = validity });
      _codes.Add(new Code() { Id = 7, Value = "1.6", Parent = code1, Validity = validity });
      _codes.Add(new Code() { Id = 8, Value = "1.7", Parent = code1, Validity = validity });
      _codes.Add(new Code() { Id = 9, Value = "2", Validity = validity });

    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
      return Ok(_codes.AsQueryable());
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
    {
      long idNumeric = Convert.ToInt64(id);
      return Ok(_codes.AsQueryable().First(x => x.Id == idNumeric));
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to follow the matrix given in the [documentation](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-02-built-in-routing-conventions), to see how capable this actually is. Unfortunately, I cannot query my object by Id

```
http://localhost:54307/Code?$expand=Validity          //--> works
http://localhost:54307/Code?$select=Value             //--> works
http://localhost:54307/Code(1)                        //--> selects the entire list
http://localhost:54307/Code?$filter=Value eq "1.1"    //--> works
```

Does anybody see my mistake (...and is willing to tell me about it)?

Comment: Yup, gets me 404  - Resource not found

Comment: Yes, I just looked it up. I was writing nonsense, sorry.

Comment: The only thing that struck my eye while reading through the examples etc was: They use `int` for the id while you are using `string` ...

Comment: That was a desperate attempt to get the method signature match the URI. A failed one. Doesn't make a difference, though.

Comment: Could it be I need to enable this like I had to do with Count(), Filter(), OrderBy() etc?

Comment: Followed the Microsoft tutorial and still couldn't get this to work. Could the underlying List and the use of IQueryable be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having spent quite some time with this issue, I stumbled across a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985730/odata-routing-in-web-api) here on SO.

The routing convention as provided by [OData docs](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-02-built-in-routing-conventions) is pretty explicit(Section 3.2 - Built-in routing conventions):
[image]

So, what I had to do to get the built-in convention working was rename my method argument from `id` to `key`.

Nested routes (below `entityset(key)`) like the ones stated [here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/) are still not working. I've decided to open another issue for this.

Example:

```
http://localhost:52072/Code(5)/Value
```